# Extract two numbers with thousand spliters from a string

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a string like this

```
1123 the first number is 12,345,654 and the 456 second number is 5,345 there are other numbers 123

desired output is 12,345,654 and 5,345
```

I want to get numbers with thousand separator "," how should i do this in kotlin or java?

kotlin version of Arvind Kumar Avinash
answer which finds the first number

```
val matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})+").matcher(body)
while (matcher.find()) {
    Log.e("number is: ",matcher.group())
}
```

Comment: Something like `[\d,]+,\d\d\d`?

Comment: i understand that i need to use regex and matcher, but i've never used them before and currently reading the docs to learn it, if you could provide a code snippet function as answer, it would really be appreciated

Comment: Some locales use a `.` for the thousands separator instead of `,` - do you know that the separator will always be a `,`? Or that the number would not use arabic text instead of 0-9?

Comment: @TylerV yes its always going to be ","

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/TCOAHL/1), `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+` to find the desired matches.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "1123 the first number is 12,345,654 and the 456 second number is 5,345 there are other numbers 123";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})+").matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
12,345,654
5,345
```

**Explanation of the regex**:

- `\d{1,3}`: One to three digits
- `(?:`: Start of non-capturing group

  - `,\d{3}`: Comma followed by three digits
- `)`: End of non-capturing group
- `+`: One or more of the previous token

Comment: doesn't cover the field. Example input that fails here: twohundredthousand minus 1 is 199,999. Maybe boost that to `\\d{1,3}`

Comment: thanks for your answer,ran it inside android studio however it finds the first number perfectly but not the second number

Comment: @khoshrang - Do you mean, it couldn't find `5,345`? It's strange because both, Regex101 and the Java code can find it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes

Comment: val matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})+").matcher(body)
        while (matcher.find()) {
            Log.e("000000000",matcher.group())
        }

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash i've added your answers kotlin version to the question

Comment: @khoshrang - Check [this](https://pl.kotl.in/er5Q1YMA9). I just learnt Kotlin for you. 